# Solving for $n$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

$$\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2} = 22$$

I'm trying to solve this equation for $n$.

If 
$$\binom{n}{0} = 1$$

Then we have that

$$1+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2} = 22 \implies \binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2} = 21$$

However, I'm stuck there. Could you help me out?

Regards

Comment: Why not write out the binomial symbols?  You'll get a polynomial in $n$ you can solve.  Or, just use trial and error.

Comment: @lulu When I used trial and error, I noticed that $n = 6$ satisfies with the condition.

Comment: So, that's a solution.  Shouldn't be too hard to argue that it's the only one.  Or, like I say, just write it out as a polynomial equation.  It's just a quadratic.

Answer (score 1):

Note that$$\binom n0+\binom n1+\binom n2=1+n+\frac{n(n-1)}2.$$Therefore, your equation is a quadratic one.

Answer (score 1):

Since for $n=7$ we get ${7\choose 2} = 21$ the $n$ can not be $\geq 8$. So you could try to solve it by inspection for all $n\leq 7$.